# Custom WPF canvas with multiple underlying visuals

Tags: wpf

Found interesting [article](http://windowspresentationfoundationinfo.blogspot.com/2014/07/wpf-visuals.html) describing how to create custom canvas control by exposing methods `Add` and `Remove` for underlying visuals of the `Panel` class. This way I could create universal canvas that can accommodate absolutely any way to draw on it, GDI+, Canvas, Drawings, etc. For example, the first layer would be `Bitmap`, second `Canvas`, third `DrawingVisual`, etc.

For simplicity, I'd like to extend existing `Canvas`, so I could have original behavior provided by default `Canvas` control + could create as many additional `Visuals` as I want to.

Here is what I have now.

```
public class VisualCanvas : Canvas
{
  protected IList<Visual> _visuals = null;
  protected override int VisualChildrenCount => _visuals.Count;
  protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) => _visuals.ElementAtOrDefault(index);

  public VisualCanvas()
  {
    _visuals = new List<Visual>();
    _visuals.Add(new DrawingVisual());

    //(_visuals[0] as DrawingVisual).RenderOpen();
  }

  public void AddVisual(Visual visual)
  {
    _visuals.Add(visual);

    base.AddVisualChild(visual);
    base.AddLogicalChild(visual);
  }

  public void DeleteVisual(Visual visual)
  {
    _visuals.Remove(visual);

    base.RemoveVisualChild(visual);
    base.RemoveLogicalChild(visual);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, `DrawingVisual` that I add in the constructor doesn't make this control to act like original `Canvas` because 2 methods that I overridden seem to expect different kind of `Visual`, not `DrawingVisual`.

**How do I make this control work like original `Canvas`**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [similar question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/88c4c3af-eb4f-4fab-8f0f-2369d92f142a/cant-add-ui-element-to-custom-canvas?forum=wpf) on MSDN. Appears to be it's not enough to override only 2 methods to keep all children in one list of visuals. Default canvas collection `InternalChildren` also needs to be taken into account.

This implementation seems to keep default canvas behavior + new visuals, but may have unpredictable behavior because 2 class collections share the same index. Looks like it would be easier to extend this class with new properties for each visual type rather than trying to override existing ones. Feel free to post better ideas and implementations.

```
public class VisualCanvas : Canvas
{
  protected IList<Visual> _visuals = new List<Visual>();
  protected override int VisualChildrenCount => _visuals.Count + InternalChildren.Count;
  protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) => _visuals.ElementAtOrDefault(index) ?? InternalChildren[index - _visuals.Count];

  public void AddVisual(Visual visual)
  {
    _visuals.Add(visual);

    base.AddVisualChild(visual);
    base.AddLogicalChild(visual);
  }

  public void DeleteVisual(Visual visual)
  {
    _visuals.Remove(visual);

    base.RemoveVisualChild(visual);
    base.RemoveLogicalChild(visual);
  }
}
```