# Multiple canvas layers on custom panel

Tags: wpf

Continuation of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65404784/custom-wpf-canvas-with-multiple-underlying-visuals/65405929#65405929). I can create custom panel or even canvas and add multiple `DrawingVisual` to it. Now, I'd like to add multiple `Canvas` controls to this custom panel. Unfortunately, `Canvas` is not being rendered.

Why `Canvas` is different from `DrawingVisual` and how to create custom panel that could show **several** `Canvas` **and several** `DrawingVisual` **at the same time**?

```
public class BoardControl : Panel
{
  protected IList<Visual> _visuals = new List<Visual>();
  protected IDictionary<dynamic, int> _maps = new Dictionary<dynamic, int>();
  protected override int VisualChildrenCount => _visuals.Count;
  protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) => _visuals.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
  //protected override IEnumerator LogicalChildren => _visuals.GetEnumerator();
  //public new UIElementCollection Children => new UIElementCollection(this, this);
  //public new UIElementCollection InternalChildren => new UIElementCollection(this, this);

  public virtual Visual this[dynamic name]
  {
    get => _maps.TryGetValue(name, out int index) ? _visuals.ElementAtOrDefault(index) : default;

    set
    {
      if (value == null)
      {
        _maps.TryGetValue(name, out int index);
        var visual = GetVisualChild(index);

        _maps.Remove(name);
        _visuals.RemoveAt(index);

        base.RemoveVisualChild(visual);
      }
      else
      {
        _maps[name] = _visuals.Count;
        _visuals.Add(value);

        //if (value is Canvas)
        //{
        //  Children.Add(value as UIElement);
        //  return;
        //}

        base.AddVisualChild(value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Canvas is a Panel, not a Control. A Canvas has no default visible elements on its own. Instead it is showing UIElements (Controls, Panels ...) that you add to its Children property. But you can make a Canvas visible if you set the Background, Width and Height properties.

A DrawingVisual can only contain drawing elements. See DrawingContext. It needs also some kind of host to show the drawings.

See this sample where they add DrawingVisuals to a host and at the end adding the host to a Canvas.

https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Visual%20Layer/DrawingVisual

Comment: I was using `DrawingVisual` on the `Canvas` in the previous question, link above. There were some issues with `DrawingVisual`. For one-time drawing, e.g. on page load, it's ok to use `DrawingVisual`, but when update is done in real-time by timer, e.g. every 10ms, visuals are not removed from the panel and cause significant memory leaks.

Comment: I suggest that you make a minimal but complete and runnable test application where you get the memory leak. Add the code to your question (or maybe a new question is better). I did a test where I draw 100 DrawingVisuals on your VisualCanvas.  I then replaced them with 100 new ones each 10 ms. The memory was steady around 75 MB. But if I add all objects to a collection, even old removed ones, then, of course, the memory grew. So check if you have a reference to old objects anywhere.